# Dynamic cropping of png images using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to create a jigsaw puzzle. I want to create the jigsaw pieces dynamically using as3. The number of pieces can vary from image to image. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please show us, what have you tried so far? Did you research the thing you need and why all the relevant results don't make it for you?

Comment: In short, yes. Make a set of pieces as either `Bitmap`s or `Sprite`s with filling controlled by a `BitmapFill` (Bitmaps are better controlled) then fill that `BitmapData` object of each one by drawing or calling `copyPixels()` using an instance of original PNG, embedded or whatnot, as source.